# Is it possible for a sting jet to form over a continental landmass?

Tags: meteorology, wind, atmospheric-circulation, mesoscale-meteorology, jet-stream

[Sting jets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sting_jet) are thought to be responsible for some of the most damaging winds associated with extratropical cyclones in the mid-latitudes. So far they have only been confirmed in the European region, associated with the [Shapiro-Keyser model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extratropical_cyclone#Shapiro-Keyser_model) of cyclone development. They have been considered to be much less important in storms forming in the Pacific which can impact the west coast of North America, though new studies indicate that they are theoretically possible, and likely occur in this region. ([Do North Pacific sting jet cyclones exist?](http://www.met.reading.ac.uk/~rb904381/ExeterWind2013_NeilHart.pdf))

Two sting jets have been [postulated](http://earthzine.org/2012/11/27/cloud-features-and-mesoscale-structure-of-non-convective-high-wind-events/) as having occurred over the (continental) Midwest USA though. Given that the Shapiro-Keyser model is applied to oceanic cyclones, is it theoretically possible that these continental forming sting jets are genuine sting jet cases?

I don't know if the sting jet [identified](http://www.atl.ec.gc.ca/weather/hurricane/bulletins/20140706143840.Arthur.info.txt.en) over the Canadian Maritimes from [ex-hurricane Arthur 2014](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurricane_Arthur_(2014)) technically nullifies this question, but I think it remains valid for those storms in the continental centre of North America.

Comment: Another link to a publication that has some discussion about the Midwest 'sting-jet': http://people.wku.edu/joshua.durkee/publications/Knox%20et%20al.%20%5B2011%5D%20Nonconvective%20high%20winds%20associated%20with%20extratropical%20cyclones.pdf

Comment: Interesting question by the way...I don't see why sting-jet-like conditions couldn't occur over continental masses, even if they were *originally* thought to be ubiquitous of the Shapiro-Keyser model...I suppose it depends how prescriptive you want to be with the model...

Comment: Sting jets in extratropical cyclones: a review, Clark & Gray, Quarterly Journal of the Royal Meteorological Society, Volume 144, Issue 713 April 2018 Part B Pages 943-969 https://rmets.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/qj.3267

Comment: Linking the definition of you're words is not including research in your question. I googled your question and found this link, https://journals.ametsoc.org/view/journals/clim/30/14/jcli-d-16-0791.1.xml Clearly answers your question.

Comment: Noticed some of your links are not definitions, but it's not a proper way to link them.